# In Dynamics CRM Unified Interface OnSave Event Doesn't Work

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-uci

I have an event handler for OnSave form event following:

```
function saveEntityForm(executionContext) {
   executionContext.getFormContext().data.save().then();
}
```

when I am clicking on Save button on the form getting a pop up with following texts:

> Saving in Progress
>
> Please wait while saving is completed Error code: 0x83215603

I am using Unified Interface.

What could be the reason of happening this issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Did you remove any part of your code? Why explicit save?

Comment: Hi  Arun, I want to execute some of my custom code on success event that's why I am trying to implement explicit save.

Comment: so the popup is coming with or without your custom logic inside save.then block? Working in classic UI? Debugged further??

Comment: Are you preventing the default save? Any chance of cyclic save events?? Could be related - https://community.dynamics.com/365/f/dynamics-365-general-forum/358043/error-0x83215605-0x83215603-on-working-script-since-change-to-uci

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks for your reply. the popup is coming on both with or without custom logic. I have also used preventing method but same thing is happening. I can see that when ever I call save() method it is popping up the error. I will give a try your suggested thread.

Comment: Hi Arun, your given thread didn't work. But I have sorted out the problem in different way. Just used settimeout to execute my custom code.

Comment: post your own answer

Comment: No need to include the .then() if you're not using it.

Answer (score 1):

The "Please wait while saving is completed" will only appear if you try to save while the form is already saving - the form does not allow two saves to happen in parallel. Thats why calling setTimeout works - it will delay calling save and by that point, the original save will be completed.

However, note that this has performance implications and, if on a slow network, may not even work since the form may not be done saving after XXX seconds!

If this code is executing in an onsave event handler, you should call preventDefault() first to stop the default save from happening, and then calling executionContext.getFormContext().data.save() will work as expected (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/save-event-arguments/preventdefault)

If this code is executing in an onchange handler for a particular control, you can try calling isDefaultPrevented or getSaveMode to determine whether the form is being saved and if so, calling save()
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/save-event-arguments/isdefaultprevented

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by myself adding setTimeout for my custom code instead of using explicit save method as following:

```
function saveEntityForm(executionContext) {
   // waiting few seconds to process the form
   setTimeout(() => {
      processForm(executionContext);
   }, 3000);
}
```